# About phases of JAVA compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I have a code:

```
package pack;
public class St
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Int y=9;
        display(23,1);
    }
}
class Animals
{
    void display(int a,int b)
    {
        System.out.println("I am Animal Class");
    }
}
```

I want to know why the compiler is only showing error first in line `Int y=9`, why it is not showing both the errors simultaneously, i.e., if I correct `Int` to `int`, then it is showing error in `display(23,1)`. I know that the compiler works in phases, can somebody please explain the various phases and their job, if you can please explain the phases with the help of an example, then I will be very grateful. And I want to know that if an error occurs in one phase, then the next successive phases are checked or not?

Comment: I'm guessing this will depend on specifically what compiler you're using. Have you tried both the Oracle JDK and OpenJDK and confirmed that they both have the same behavior here?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I just tried it using javac from OpenJDK 1.7.0_65, and it showed both errors immediately.

Comment: I am using oracle JDK 1.8.0_45

Comment: @RajMalhotra *can somebody please explain the various phases and their job,* That would be too broad for SO. Can you narrow it down to a particular phase? That being said, a quick Google search gives a good number of hits.

Comment: @ChetanKinger,Can you please tell me that Int y=9,is checked by which phase,lexical or syntax phase of the compiler and which phase checks display(23,1) in my code above.Thanks

Comment: "Cannot find symbol" errors happen when symbols are resolved, which happens during the semantic analysis stage (which happens after lexing and parsing).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ javac St.java
St.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Int y=9;
        ^
  symbol:   class Int
  location: class St
St.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        display(23,1);
        ^
  symbol:   method display(int,int)
  location: class St
2 errors
$ javac -Xmaxerrs 1 St.java
St.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Int y=9;
        ^
  symbol:   class Int
  location: class St
1 error
```

Both locally with JDK 1.7 and on CodingGrouding with JDK 1.8, I'm getting both errors.

If I had to guess I'd say it's a compiler-specific behavior. One could argue that you wouldn't be fixing all your errors at the same time, or that an incorrect variable declaration could cause a bunch of false positives down the line and so showing all of them might not be relevant.

Regarding phases, the Wikipedia article on [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) mentions

> lexical analysis, preprocessing, parsing, semantic analysis
>   (syntax-directed translation), code generation, and code optimization

Comment: "if you have a lexical error (e.g. invalid characters), the compiler won't actually bother taking your file through syntax analysis" This is generally not true as most lexers work lazily in the sense that they won't actually analyse the whole file before parsing starts, but rather analyse one bit at a time whenever the parser requests more tokens. So a lexical error would happen after parsing already started when the parser requests a new token and the lexer finds an invalid one.

Comment: Fair enough, I removed that bit, a it might be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Having done a custom compiler during my school time, I found that some compilers work from top to bottom hence why we get the top most errors first. In my compiler class we learned that compilers work by taking everything in one character at a time. It can detect when something is something like Int y= 9; when it starts picking up the (i-n-t) part. It knows or expects the next couple characters like "y" to be the variable followed by either a number or semicolon. If you want to learn more I suggest reading or looking up specific compilers and just how exactly they work. How they parse through .java files or parse through .cpp files. Hope it helps

Comment: This is an actual example I did but you'd have to look into how it works. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0i77lrwjmxa9qhp/4_28_14notes.docx?dl=0

Comment: Unresolved symbols aren't parse errors. The workings of the parser don't affect how such errors are handled.